# How to make a custom zoom the default?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox I cannot see option that lets me keep my customized zoom as the default. Is there such an option at all?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this extension: [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint/). It lets you set the global zoom settings as well as zoom settings for individual sites.